# C++. Задан текст. Напечатать все слова в алфавитном порядке.

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Не могу правильно выполнить задание, уже 4-ый час мучаюсь. Помогите пожалуйста :) И еще, просьба отредактировать мой код, а не кидать свои очень сложные и эльфийские примеры :)

```
//Задан текст. Напечатать все слова в алфавитном порядке. 
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "Russian");
    string s;
    char a[34];
    char str[] = "god please work correctly ";
    int j, index = 0;
    for (j = 'a'; j <= 'z'; ++j)
    {
        a[index] = j;
        // разделяем на слова и помещаем их в строку
        for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
        {
            if (str[i] != ' ')       // если это не пробел
                s.push_back(str[i]); // помещаем символы в строку
            else
            {
                cout << "->" << s << "<-" << endl; // отладка
                s.clear();
            }
        }

        // проверяем первую и последнюю букву после последней итерации
        if ((s.size() != 0) && (s[0] == a[j]) && (s[s.size() - 1] != ' '))
        {
            cout << "->" << s << "<-" << endl; // отладка
        }
        a[index] = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Ну и задачи ты, барин, ставишь" (с) Ну вот вы, получив слово в s, тут же его затираете и выполняете какие-то странные манипуляции с `a`. Ну как это редактировать? лично я пас...

Comment: Зачем вы очищаете вашу строку, если одним из элементов будет пробел? Функция `clear` полностью очищает строку, если что. Потом, разве вы меняете `index` где-то? Потом, почему в одних местах для индексирования используете тип `int`, а в других - `std::size_t`?

Comment: Для комментариев есть комментарии

Comment: @pinguin это не комментарий, а указания ошибок автора

Comment: @стручок, но ошибок у автора очень много и ваше замечание не решает его проблемы, так что ваше замечание действительно должно быть в комментариях. Это не ответ

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Приведите ваш ответ с указанием всех возможных ошибок автора и он наберет соответствующее количество голосов. В чём проблема? Ответ является полезным, комментарии на этом ресурсы - бесполезны, т.к. никак не индексируются

Comment: @ARHovsepyan у меня проблем нет. Я же написал - любой относящийся к вопросу ответ полезней, чем любой даже самый полезный комментарий на данном ресурсе. Если вам не нравится мой ответ, то не надо переводить его в комментарий, достаточно поставить минус, объяснить причину и при желании привести лучший ответ

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Кстати, что лучше: потратить полчаса на сочинение ответа или полчаса спорить, что чужой ответ - плохой? По-моему ответ очевиден

Comment: @ARHovsepyan 1) я вас не учил манерам; 2) я объяснил, почему не надо переводить мой ответ в комментарий; 3) про рейтинг вообще ни слова не говорил

Comment: 1. Откуда информация, что комментарии не идексируются поисковиками? 2. Ты считаешь, кто-то будет искать этот вопрос по тексту из этого ответа? 3. Вообще-то действительно больше похоже на комментарий, чем на ответ. 4. Комментарий по поводу clear уже есть, только менее чёткий. 5. Информация про size_t vs int уж точно к проблеме не относится и может быть либо отдельным комментарием, либо приписана к нормальному ответу.

Answer (score 1):

Просто сложить их в set или multiset: https://ideone.com/SiNzwy

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string s;
  set <string> res;
  // multiset <string> res;

  while (cin >> s)
    res.insert(s);

  for (string s : res)
    cout << s << ' ';

  return 0;
}
```

Словом считается любая группа непробельных символов, сравнение с учётом регистра.

Comment: строка уже имеется, и нужно из этой строки  слова сортировать. Ваш случай для ввода отдельных слов. Для данной же задачи  лучше  подходит istringstream...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, да, если строка уже есть, то можно через него. Код от этого почти не изменится, просто с вводом понагляднее выглядит. К тому же в вопросе не говорится, что строка уже есть.

Comment: char str[] = "god please work correctly "; по моему  убеждает, что строка задана

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, а по-моему это заглушка подразумевающая "ввод потом напишу" :)

Comment: сделаю исключение (такие комментарии я считаю неуместными)  для того что просто высказать то, что сейчас думаю.  За долгое время в этом сайте не трудно было замечать, что вы очень умны и очень многое (уж точно больше меня) знаете. Исходя из этого не буду спорить, но я уверен, что автору нужно именно так, как я говорил...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, я допускаю, что это может быть так (хотя мне оно и кажется маловероятным), но надеюсь, что автор вместо cin сможет воспользоваться istringstream'ом самостоятельно.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan к сожалению у меня очень много ограничений на использование команд таких как вектор, ваш istringstream и другие. Мне  вообще надо было выполнить задание без использования string, при этом как то справившись с заданием используя только массивы, циклы и если, cin get и strlen не в счет. Так что к сожалению, мне вариант выше не покатит :(

Comment: @aquarus91, я так и догадывался, потому и не написал ответ, поскольку с одной стороны вы используете  string(С++) с другой стороны хотите писать на С